# Problemas con activeElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy tratando de convertir los valores de los input que  son numeros en decimales pero la funcion activeElement no me obtiene los valores del input activo y me da un error, espero que me puedan ayudar o sujerirme otro modo de hacerlo,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nuevoServicio").click(function () {
        var tableReg = document.getElementById("tablaserviciosprest");
        $("#tablaserviciosprest").append("<tr>" + tableReg.rows[1].innerHTML + "</tr>");

        $('.eliminalinea').off().click(function (e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();        });
        addcambios()
    });
    addcambios()
});

function addcambios() {
    //token
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    //tokenn

    function parseFloatHTML(element) {
        return parseFloat(element.innerHTML.replace(/[^\d\.\-]+/g, '')) || 0;
    }

    function parsePrice(number) {
        return number.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1,');
    }

    function updateNumber(e) {
        console.log(document.activeElement);
        var
            activeElement = document.activeElement,

            value = parseFloat(activeElement.innerHTML),
            wasPrice = activeElement.innerHTML == parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(activeElement));

        if (!isNaN(value) && (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.wheelDeltaY)) {
            e.preventDefault();

            value += e.keyCode == 38 ? 1 : e.keyCode == 40 ? -1 : Math.round(e.wheelDelta * 0.025);
            value = Math.max(value, 0);

            activeElement.innerHTML = wasPrice ? parsePrice(value) : value;
        }


document.addEventListener('mousewheel', updateNumber);
document.addEventListener('keyup', updateNumber);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3>Adicionar Servicio Prestado</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body ">

        <div class="panel panel-default ">
            <div class="panel-body 2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="areaSP" class="control-label col-lg-1">Área*:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="areaSP" name="areaT">
                            <option value="">Seleccione Área ...</option>
                            {% for area in area_List %}
                                <option value="{{ area.pk }}">{{ area.area }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="clienteSP" class="control-label col-lg-1">Cliente*:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="clienteSP" name="areaT">
                            <option value="">Seleccione Cliente ...</option>
                            {% for cliente in cliente_List %}
                                <option value="{{ cliente.pk }}">{{ cliente.nombreEmp }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="carnetI" class="control-label col-lg-2">Servicios Prestados*:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tablaserviciosprest">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Área</th>
                                <th>Servicio</th>
                                <th>Precio CUP</th>
                                <th>Precio CUC</th>
                                <th>Precio Total</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Costo Total</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr style="display:none; ">
                                <td class="col-lg-2">
                                    <select id="seleccionarArea[]"
                                            class="select2_single form-control select2-hidden-accessible seleccionarArea"
                                            name="seleccionarArea[]">
                                        <option value="">Seleccione Área ...</option>
                            <option value="1">Comercio</option>
                            <option value="2">Aplicaciones Informáticas</option>
                            <option value="3">Desarrollo</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-lg-2">
                                    <select id="seleccionarServicioP[]"
                                            class="select2_single form-control select2-hidden-accessible seleccionarServicioP"
                                            name="seleccionarServicioP[]" disabled="">
                                        <option value="">Seleccione Servicio ...</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="precioCUP" name="precioCUP[]" placeholder="CUP"
                                           class="form-control">
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="precioCUC" name="precioCUC[]" placeholder="CUC"
                                           class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="precioTotal" name="precioTotal[]" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Total"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Cantidad"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="costoTotal" name="costoTotal[]" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Total"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="eliminalinea btn btn-default btn-xs col-lg-offset-4">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus " style="color: red"></span></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-lg-2">
                                    <select id="seleccionarArea[]"
                                            class="select2_single form-control select2-hidden-accessible seleccionarArea"
                                            name="seleccionarArea[]">
                                        <option value="">Seleccione Área ...</option>
                            <option value="1">Comercio</option>
                            <option value="2">Aplicaciones Informáticas</option>
                            <option value="3">Desarrollo</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-lg-2">
                                    <select id="seleccionarServicioP[]"
                                            class="select2_single form-control select2-hidden-accessible seleccionarServicioP"
                                            name="seleccionarServicioP[]" disabled>
                                        <option value="">Seleccione Servicio ...</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="precioCUP[]" name="precioCUP[]" placeholder="CUP"
                                           class="form-control">
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="precioCUC[]" name="precioCUC[]" placeholder="CUC"
                                           class="form-control"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="precioTotal[]" name="precioTotal[]" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Total"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="cantidad[]" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Cantidad"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="costoTotal[]" name="costoTotal[]" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Total"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="eliminalinea btn btn-default btn-xs col-lg-offset-4" disabled>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus " style="color: red"></span></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button type="button" id="nuevoServicio" class="btn btn-danger nuevoServicio">Nuevo Servicio
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="porCobrar" class="control-label col-lg-2">Por Cobrar:</label>
                    <div class="checkbox col-lg-7">
                        <input id="porCobrar" name="porCobrar" type="checkbox" checked>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Guardar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: has copiado todo el codigo javascript ? por que no veo donde llamas a las funciones, por ejemplo a  updateNumber()

Comment: a si no me di cuenta me falto la linea que mientras escribe el numero se va ejecutando la funcion updateNumber()

Comment: edita el código que has puesto, por favor

Comment: disculpa la demora en editar es que me complique em el trabajo y en la casa no tengo internet

Comment: Tranquilo, lo reviso en un par de horas, ahora estoy trabajando

Comment: esta bien yo estare por aqui revisando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para coger los valores del input de un `activeElement` lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
activeElement.value
```

el `innerHTML` te devuelve el HTML del objecto , tu función debe de quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
function updateNumber(e) {
    //console.log(document.activeElement);
    var
        activeElement = document.activeElement,
        value = parseFloat(activeElement.value),
        wasPrice = activeElement.innerHTML == parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(activeElement));
    ....
    ....

}
```

el resto corre por tu cuenta, espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.

Comment: esta bien muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si he resuelto tu pregunta no olvides ponerla como respondida .